# Render ajax query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

I am tryign to render an Ajax query , but I just dont figure out how.

This is the form:

```
<%= form_tag(root_path, :method => "post",:id =>"formid", :remote => true) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "El que quiero") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :quiero, nil, :class => 'drug_autocomplete' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :number1 %>

  <%= label_tag(:number1, "El modelo que tengo") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :tengo, nil, :class => 'drug_autocomplete' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :number2 %>

  <%= label_tag(:size1, "Talla de el que tengo") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :size1%>

  <%= submit_tag("Do it!",:id =>"submit_but") %>

<% end %>
```

This is pretty much the controller

```
def index
    size1 = params[:size1]
    number1 = params[:number1]
    number2 = params[:number2]
    quiero = params[:quiero]
    tengo = params[:tengo]

if (item1 and item2)

      @itemsok = Contribution.where("first_item_id = ?",item1.id).where("second_item_id = ?",item2.id).where("second_item_grade = ?",size1)

      end
```

Ok, so when I push the button to send, I can see that the consult in the database is being made, when I write correct values it returns it and all works perfectly.

What I dont know how to do is to render the items from the query.
In the view I have a table where I want to fill the information in...
I've already done it without AJAX, and it is like this.

```
<%if not @itemsok.nil? 
  @itemsok.each do |searches|
%>
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="width:100px;"><%= searches.first_item.description %>  </td>
  <td style="width:150px; font-size:30px;"><%= searches.first_item_grade %>  </td>


  <td style="width:150px;"><%= searches.second_item.description %> </td>
  <td style="width:150px; font-size:30px;"><%= searches.second_item_grade %>  </td>
  <td style="width:150px; font-size:18px;"><a href="<%= contribution_path(searches.id) %>">Show</a>  </td>


</tr>
</table>
```

Ok, so it takes the variable in the controller, and if is not nill, it renders the data (wich in a normal request, I can access reloading the page)

How can I render the items from my query?
Any hint would be very appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render the AJAX response in RAILS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797692/how-to-render-the-ajax-response-in-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, _search.html.erb

```
<%if not @itemsok.nil? 
  @itemsok.each do |searches|
%>
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="width:100px;"><%= searches.first_item.description %>  </td>
  <td style="width:150px; font-size:30px;"><%= searches.first_item_grade %>  </td>


  <td style="width:150px;"><%= searches.second_item.description %> </td>
  <td style="width:150px; font-size:30px;"><%= searches.second_item_grade %>  </td>
  <td style="width:150px; font-size:18px;"><a href="<%= contribution_path(searches.id) %>">Show</a>  </td>


</tr>
</table>
```

search.js.erb

```
$('#container').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'search/search')%>");
```